# How to refer to a cross joint table in PHP on a read only mySQL server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ive cross joint two tables and gotten rid of any duplicates in the table. However, the mysql is read only therefore I'm unable to create or insert into a new table. I was just wondering whether there is any way to refer to this cross join table later on in code?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM club 
CROSS JOIN team
WHERE club.cid=team.clubID";
```

Comment: Why CROSS JOIN? You query is INNER JOIN - simply move the condition from WHERE to ON clause. *and gotten rid of any duplicates* What duplicates? apply DISTINCT. Or provide more data - it can be an example.

Comment: CROSS JOIN of  (a,b) with (c,d) will give you

a,c
a,d
b,c
b,d

Ie.. all possible combinations.

I've really never run into the situation where cross join is useful. Generally what you'd need is INNER JOIN or OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Are you allowed to do "CREATE VIEW" or even "CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW" on the server? Or is it really really read-only?

Comment: the sql is completely readable only sadly, in this  code im joining two complete tables, that have overlapping columns with the same information, so the WHERE statement removes them. Using your examples of an INNER JOIN, how would you go about doing this for this example, and after the inner join how would you refer to this new table in the php code later on?

Comment: We cannot use inner join as none of the columns match so is there any other way?

Comment: Surely, `WHERE club.cid=team.clubID` do match or you wouldn't get any result. The part where I'd appreciate some clarifications is when you say you want to refer to a result set later on in PHP. Are you asking how to actually launch the query and retrieve the results?